# Determine the NSString encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsstring, ios7

I am using the following code to display a string:

```
[self.messageAreaLabel loadData:[self.alert.message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                           MIMEType:@"text/rtf"
                   textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
                            baseURL:nil];
```

Where messageAreaLabel is UIWebview trying to display message. I invoke a service which returns a message I need to display.

But the service sometimes returns RTF and sometimes just a normal string. The above line of code works only for RTF. How should I deal with normal text?

```
[self.messageAreaLabel loadHTMLString:self.alert.message baseURL:nil]
```

I can use the above line to display a normal string. But that does not work for RTF.

How can I handle both types of strings in the code? I did not find a way to determine the `[self.alert.message]` encoding type.

This needs to work both in iOS6 and iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with encoding. When you say service, I'm assuming that you're talking about a web service. You need to keep the MIME type returned by the service and pass it to the webview.